# Angular Services/Factories with $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm a Web Developer new to AngularJS. I've been reading @toddmotto's Angular styleguide (https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide). I am currently building a CRUD app grabbing data via a RESTful API.

I'm a bit stuck on services and/or factories.

I had it working previously (code below) but since looking at Todd's styleguide - I would like to move my logic from the controller to the service/factory but I'm not sure how to get what I had before working in the new structure.

Does anybody have any ideas?

**Previous UserService.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function UserService($resource) {
        return $resource('https://api.path.com/users/:id', { }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET'
            },
            create: {
                method: 'POST'
            },
            update: {
                method: 'PUT'
            },
            delete: {
                method: 'DELETE'
            }
        });
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('UserService', UserService);
})();
```

Currently, I have:

**UserController.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function UserController(UserService) {
        var _this = this;

        UserService
            .getUsers()
            .then(function (response) {
                _this.users = response;
                console.table(response);
            });
        };
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('UserController', UserController);
})();
```

**UserService.js**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function UserService($resource) {
        var service = {};

        service.getUsers = function () {
            return $resource('https://api.path.com/users');
        };

        return service;
    }

    angular
        .module('app')
        .factory('UserService', UserService);
})();
```

**EDIT**

```
    var resource =  $resource(baseUrl + '/users/:id', { }, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET'
        },
        create: {
            method: 'POST'
        },
        update: {
            method: 'PUT'
        },
        delete: {
            method: 'DELETE'
        }
    });

    service.getUsers = function () {
        return resource.query().$promise;
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
service.getUsers = function () {
    return $resource('https://api.path.com/users').query().$promise;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dfsq. That (sort of) worked. I modified it a bit as I was getting an error as I was receiving an object back instead of an array. My new code is above - do you think this is the best way of accomplishing it?