# Storing results of Angular Resource in Factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource, angular-services, angular-controller

I'm currently using Angular $resource to make an api, and I would like to keep those results in a service rather than a controller because every time I call the controller the results get called again, and thus any changes that were made get deleted.

I have tried answers given in several SO articles including:

[AngularJS: Using Shared Service(with $resource) to share data between controllers, but how to define callback functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12772255/angularjs-using-shared-servicewith-resource-to-share-data-between-controller)

and

[Angular Services/Factories with $resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26362130/angular-services-factories-with-resource)

but neither of those have worked because I need the results stored in the service, but accessible for the controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think $resource requires a lot of developer work to be used more effectively. Which made me switched to this framework: http://www.js-data.io/docs/home

Comment: Hey Louie,

I looked into that an it looks really interesting, unfortunately though I have to use angular because I am building an app with Ionic.  Thank you though!

Comment: It's framework agnostic, so it works with angular! :D

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular's Services/Factories are singletons, if you just put the value of the callback on the services variable, you'll be able to get it from anywhere.
Sample:

```
angular.module('foo',[])
  .service('FooService', ['$resource', function($resource){
      this.users = []
      $resource('/users')
         .get(function(users) {
            this.users = users
          })

     this.getUsers = function(){
       return this.users
     }
  })
  .controller('FooController', ['$scope','FooService', function($scope, FooService){
     $scope.users = FooService.getUsers()
  })
```

It's nice to remember that $resource is perfoming an asynchronous request to backend, so it would be nice to guarantee this data it's going to be available before you try to get it from the service.

Comment: Hey Igor,

Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately that still is not working.  I am still getting an empty array in the controller.  The object is in the service now, but whenever I try and retrieve it in the controller it is just an empty array.

Comment: `this` in the `.get` callback is not referring to your service and even if it is, the reference to this.users is overwritten by a new reference. Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/daqkpr9P4c3KnwBVX30z?p=preview It works but it is a bad pattern because you are implicit sharing data (users) through your app. Bugs will occur easily.

Answer (score 0):

Always use promises!

```
angular.module('foo',[])
  .service('FooService', ['$resource', function($resource){
    this.getUsers = function () {
      return $resource('/users', .get().$promise;
    };
  })
  .controller('FooController', ['$scope','FooService', function($scope, FooService){
    FooService.getUsers()
      .then(function (users) {
        $scope.users = users;
      });
  });
```

You could additionally refactor the `$resource('/users')` into a `UserResource` factory and inject `UserResource` into the service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Frank, but unfortunately this doesn't work either.  I need the users object stored in the service because I am making updates to it and so I can't call getUsers everytime because then the updates would not be there